# The difference between List<MyClass> and MyClass[]

Tags: c#, .net

What is the difference between `List<MyClass> and MyClass[]` in C#.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyClass[]` is an array, and once set in size it can't grow.

A `List<MyClass>`, however, can have things constantly added to it.